# Symfony2 execute script from cron job

Tags: symfony, cron

I need to create a script to periodically send emails to some users. I have thought in creating a function in the controller and a path in the routing and in the cron job call www.mydomain.com/send for example.

But i don't think that is the best way to do it because whatever user could call the script.. What is the correct way to do so?

```
class UserController extends Controller{

    public function sendAction(){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Shameless plug but you could run the code using the cron module in prggmr, this would allow you to run the PHP code directly http://prggmr.org/modules/cron.html ... not the Symfony2 why but an option and its not user accessible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your feeling is right, using Controller actions is not the best way to solve your task.

There's a much better way - [Console Commands](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html).
It's much safer (no risk that somebody from outside calls it) and faster (much faster to load).